# How do I correctly use ADDIS and ADDI to sum a 32 bit constant directly to a register?

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I have been trying to use the ADDIS and ADDI instructions for a basic function that sums constants to an array, I followed the instructions in pages 48 and 49 of https://cr.yp.to/2005-590/powerpc-cwg.pdf, but the behavior isn't what I expected.

What I'm trying to do is create this function in assembler, but for certain constants ADDIS decrements them by 1, and the behavior is not consistent with what the manual says, that is checking if bit 16 is set.
GCC and clang generate the instructions correctly, what is the actual rule they are using?
Not doing the incrementing or implementing the rule as the manual says just gives me wrong sums.

Tested in a ppc970 machine, running a 64 bit linux kernel and userspace.

Example of compiler assembler output from C function:

```
void func(int* r){
r[0] += r[0] + 0x9f321062; //addis r3,r3,0x9f32 #has bit 16 set to 1 but is not incremented.
                           //addi  r3,r3,0x1062

r[1] += r[1] + 0x760ae53;  //addis r4,r4,0x761  #compiler correctly increments this from 0x0760 to 0x0761, but bit 16 of this number is 0!
                           //addi r4,r4,0xae53
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> has bit 16 set to 1 but is not incremented.

PowerPC's `addi` instruction works similar to the instruction with the same name on MIPS CPUs:

You can add a number in the range (-0x8000) to (+0x7FFF) to a register.

The `addis` instruction will add a multiple of 0x10000 to a register.

Because 0x9f321062 = 0x9f320000 + 0x1062, you can add 0x9f321062 to a register by adding 0x9f320000 and 0x1062 to the register using one `addis` and one `addi` instruction.

The important thing here is that the highest bit of the 16-bit number 0x1062 is clear, which means that 0x1062 is not greater than 0x7FFF and therefore in the range `addi` can deal with.

Now let's look at the other case:

0x760ae53 = 0x7600000 + 0xae53, so you could add 0x760ae53 to a register by adding 0x7600000 and 0xae53 to the register. Unfortunately, `addi` can only operate with the range (-0x8000) to (+0x7FFF), so adding 0xae53 does not work.

If the highest bit of the operand of `addi` is set, the `addi` instruction sign-extends the value, which actually means that the instruction adds (the negative value) (N-0x10000) instead of (the positive value) N to the register.

So you have to do the calculation the following way:

0x760ae53 = 0x7600000 + (0xae53 - 0x10000) + 0x10000 = 0x7610000 + (0xae53 - 0x10000)

In other words: You have to increment the operand of `addis` (0x760) by one to compensate the effect that `addi` will subtract 0x10000.

> bit 16

Please note that PowerPC documentation uses very confusing bit numbering, which even seems to differ from CPU to CPU:

Some documentation of a 32-bit (!) automotive PowerPC used register names of "bit 32" (highest bit) to "bit 63" (lowest bit) so bit numbers 0 to 31 did not even exist...

Comment: Other than that insane example, PowerPC numbers bits from high = 0 to low = `width-1`.  This is the opposite of everyone else, but I think you forgot to actually say what the PPC convention is, just that it's confusing :P

Comment: Thanks to both, that was it! By checking if the highest bit is set in the lowest 16bits I can know when to increment the highest half.

Answer (score 1):

This makes sense if the immediate is *sign*-extended to 32-bit.

Notice that `0xae53` has its high bit set, so it would sign extend to `0xffffae53`.  i.e. it would subtract 1 from the high half as well as adding `0xae53` to the low half (with potential carry into high half of course).

So it's not possible to write `add r4, r4, 0x0000ae53`, because that would need a 16-bit *unsigned* immediate, or a wider-than-16-bit signed immediate.

But maybe the compiler-generated asm uses the `0xae53` notation to just show you the bit-pattern of the immediate without the implicit higher bits?

(Sorry, I'm not a PowerPC expert, I don't know how the assemblers behave.)